# Присвоение значения в DataGridViewTextBoxCell.Value. Выбрасывает System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения

Код на C#:

```
DataGridViewRow Row = new DataGridViewRow();
DataGridViewCell Cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

Row.Cells.AddRange(Cell);

Cell.Value = "123";   // На самом деле тут берется значение типа string из структуры
```

Ошибка в последней строке: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Заданный аргумент находится вне диапазона допустимых значений.
Имя параметра: rowIndex"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже разобрался: нужно вначале присваивать значение, а затем добавлять в Row:

```
DataGridViewRow Row = new DataGridViewRow();
DataGridViewCell Cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();

Cell.Value = "123";

Row.Cells.AddRange(Cell);
```